# Scaling Akka actors

Tags: scala, akka

I was curious to know whether resizing, or in this case specifically increasing the number of actors in an actor pool on a single node system really affects performance.

Depending on the pressure on the system akka resizer can create more instances of the actor in the same actor pool. However, does it really affect performance if all this is done running on the same hardware ?

Consider this following scenario.

I have a quad core system with hyperthreading. At any given point the system can run 8 threads. Assuming that most operations that are performed by the actor are CPU bound, what can one gain by increasing the number of actors in the pool from 20 to 40 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you'll gain nothing from going from 20 to 40. If you're really totally CPU-bound, you'll probably gain a tiny bit scaling back to 8 actually. As always in these kind of situation, a good benchmark is the way to go !

If you want to make this scaling dependent on the computer running the code, `Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors` is there for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of increasing the actor pool size, decrease it to a size of, at most, eight and use a custom [dispatcher](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/dispatchers.html) that is limited to, at most, eight threads. For example, in your `application.conf`:

```
my-thread-pool-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  thread-pool-executor {
    core-pool-size-min = 2
    core-pool-size-factor = 2.0
    core-pool-size-max = 8
  }
  throughput = 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, increasing the number of actors does impact the performance of the system. Hence whenever we specify the akka resizer, we specify the upper and lower limit. Ideally, a lot of thought must be given to configuring this limit as if we set a very high upper limit on actor instances, then it creates a huge performance bottleneck. However, setting a very low number for instances might defeat the whole purpose of akka elasticity.

For Quad core systems, I am having an upper limit of 100 and lower limit of 10 actors and so far we have not faced any problems. 
You can set your .conf file as

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /myrouter2 {
    router = round-robin
    resizer {
      lower-bound = 10
      upper-bound = 100
    }
  }
}
```